# Can safari/chrome/opera make ajax requests while an upload is in progress?

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari, google-chrome, opera

Basically i am making a simple ajax request

```
function upload(){


            setInterval(function callMeOften()
            {
                $.ajax({
                   method: 'get',
                   url : 'uploadinfo.php?unique_id=<?php echo $some_uniq_id; ?>',
                   dataType : 'text',
                   success: function(text){ updatebar(text); },
                   error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                      alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                   }
                });

            }, 5000);

        }

        function updatebar(per){

            $('#updateMe').animate({"width" : per});

        }
```

to a php script

```
$unique_id = $_GET['unique_id'];
$progress = uploadprogress_get_info($unique_id);

if(function_exists("uploadprogress_get_info")) {


if (floor(($progress['bytes_total']/1024)/1024) > 100){

    echo "run";

} else {

    if ($progress['bytes_uploaded'] == 0 || $progress['bytes_total'] == 0){

        echo "100";

    } else {

        echo floor($progress['bytes_uploaded'] / $progress['bytes_total'] * 100);

    }

}
```

}

This function upload(); is called using the onsubmit(); action of a file upload form

```
<form id="something" onsubmit="upload();" action="status.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

I am using relative paths and the request works in FF and IE, but in chrome, safari and opera the ajax requests are not even fired while the upload is in progress.

What's going on?

EDIT: In the end i just showed the upload progress in a separate window that was created using the onsubmit action and re-sized and reposition to the center of the screen, looks alright and is by far the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

As per I know there can be two request for one server domain can be active for the browser. That is if your server domain name is 'code.mydomain.com' then there can be atmost 2 request open at a time. In your case first one is file uploading request. You have to check do you have any other active request apart form uploading in specified browsers.

Comment: Turns out it's a bug, in any webkit based browser all xhr is essentially blocked until the file upload is complete. to bypass this you have to dynamically create an iframe and run the ajax requests from within it.

Comment: @SamGregory, where can I read more about that? I'm having the exactly same problem on my site. Not about the iframe implementation but about the blocking of xhr when there is a file upload. Thanks..