# jQuery $.ajax() is firing the server request but never gets response on google chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, jquery

I tested this on firefox and ie and worked. But when testing on chrome, **I see in the firebug console that the request never loads**.

This is the test page: http://gotune.to/index2.php

And here is the function + $.ajax() request.

```
function getProgress(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: "getprogress.php",                         

        //Pass our upload identifier as a parameter.
        data: {uid: id},

        success: function (d) {

            //Get the output as an integer.
            var progress = parseInt(d, 10);

            //If upload progress is not 100, change bar percentage and update again.
            if (progress != '100') {

                $('#ProgressBar').css('width', progress + '%');

                //We aren't done, update again.
                getProgress(id);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Tried with

```
    },

    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus+" - "+errorThrown);
    }
```

But still not working.

Comment: How about adding an error Handler to see if there is any error returned by the request?

Comment: You see in Chrome's Firebug Console?

Comment: @SLaks: hi, yes i see that the POST http://www.gotune.to/getprogress.php request is triggered but it also shows a loading gift, it never ends loading

Comment: @ifaour: No, its that i make the upload to actually dont move the uploaded file for security reasons. But the ajax request should work.

Comment: @Hernantz - no it's not, I'm getting a warnings on the upload2.php and the code is halting there..

Comment: @ifaour: yes upload2.php is broken with the porpouse of preventing the upload of strange files to my server. Till you get the error, do yo see the upload progress bar working?

Comment: it just appear for a second before getting redirected to the upload2.php page and no nothing is logged in Firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a web research for this issue if found this:

> Turns out it's a bug, in any webkit
>   based browser all ajax is essentially
>   blocked until the file upload is
>   complete. to bypass this you have to
>   dynamically create an iframe and run
>   the ajax requests from within it.

So is a problem of the webkit browsers, thanks @ifaour for your time.

THE BUG REPORT CAN BE FOUND HERE: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23933

Comment: found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185238/can-safari-chrome-opera-make-ajax-requests-while-an-upload-is-in-progress